File downloading from S3 using Presigned URL fails
I have a file of size 254MB stored in S3, for which I have created a pre-signed-url and stored it in db with expiration time of 1 hr
so now if i am using axios.get(fileURL) to download that file than according to network tab i can see 2 calls are made 1st one took around 40 secs and size is 260 MB
but second call fails with 403

It sounds like your client is making 2 requests. What's your question?
